# Youtube API wont work

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have this script as described here: [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!-- ... -->
  <body>
    <h1>Youtube Video</h1>

    <div id="player"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the IFrame Player API code asyncronously
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // Creating an iframe and youtube player
      var player;
      function onYoutubeIframeAPIReady(){
        console.log("Youtube API Loaded");

        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'LSwbPyIP-gY',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // When video_player is ready, call this function
      function onPlayerReady(event){
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event){
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done){
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }

      function stopVideo(){
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After reloading the page, nothing happing. So, at the end of the script, I call this function:

```
onYoutubeIframeAPIReady();
```

Doing this, gives me an error:

> (index):25 Uncaught ReferenceError: YT is not defined

But when I check the generated source code, I see this two lines before my script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="www-widgetapi-script" src="https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vflWkc-3E/www-widgetapi.js" async=""></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
```

If the IFrame Player API code are being loaded, why I am getting the error "YT is not defined" ? What am I missing?

To run this test, I am using Google Chrome 51.0.2704.79 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to call `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady` by yourself.

Youtube server side code call it for you.

Check in their code you will find this code:

```
    var Sb = l("onYTReady");
    Sb && Sb();
    var Tb = l("onYouTubeIframeAPIReady");
    Tb && Tb();
    var Ub = l("onYouTubePlayerAPIReady");
    Ub && Ub();
```

You just load the script and it call your function.

Comment: so, if I don't have to call by myself, what should I do to make it work? I am asking this because, If I don't call `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady()` function, nothing happens.

Comment: after running `git diff`, I got the real problem :). I was writing `function onYoutubeIframeAPIReady()` instead of `function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()`.